# Reshape and pad a tensor given a list of lengths

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have given a 2d tensor `in` of shape `a x b` like the following (where `a = 9` and each of `A1`, `A2`, ..., `C2` represents a `b`-dimensional vector):

[image: in]

Furthermore, I have an array of `lengths`, where `sum(lengths) = a` and each entry is a positive integer:

[image: lengths]

Then I would like to obtain a 3d output tensor `out`, where the first `lengths[0]` entries of `in` form the first row, the next `lengths[1]` entries of `in` form the second row, and so on. That is, the output tensor should have the shape `len(lengths) x max(lengths) x b`, and be padded with zeros (each `0` in the below picture represents a `b`-dimensional zero vector):

[image: out]

As this is part of a neural network that is trained using backpropagation, all operations used **must be differentiable**. How can this be achieved (ideally, **with good performance**) using PyTorch?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation using `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence()`:

```
in_tensor = torch.rand((9, 3))
print(in_tensor)
print(36*'=')
lengths = torch.tensor([3, 4, 2])
cum_len = 0
y = []
for idx, val in enumerate(lengths):
    y.append(in_tensor[cum_len : cum_len+val])
    cum_len += val
print(torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(y, batch_first=True)))
```

output:

```
# in_tensor of shape (9 x 3)
tensor([[0.9169, 0.3549, 0.6211],
        [0.4832, 0.5475, 0.8862],
        [0.8708, 0.5462, 0.9374],
        [0.4605, 0.1167, 0.5842],
        [0.1670, 0.2862, 0.0378],
        [0.2438, 0.5742, 0.4907],
        [0.1045, 0.5294, 0.5262],
        [0.0805, 0.2065, 0.2080],
        [0.6417, 0.4479, 0.0688]])
====================================
# out tensor of shape (len(lengths) x max(lengths) x b), in this case b is 3
tensor([[[0.9169, 0.3549, 0.6211],
         [0.4832, 0.5475, 0.8862],
         [0.8708, 0.5462, 0.9374],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]],

        [[0.4605, 0.1167, 0.5842],
         [0.1670, 0.2862, 0.0378],
         [0.2438, 0.5742, 0.4907],
         [0.1045, 0.5294, 0.5262]],

        [[0.0805, 0.2065, 0.2080],
         [0.6417, 0.4479, 0.0688],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below. It is differentiable and can work with backprop.

```
def sequence_to_padding(x, length): 
    # declare the shape, it can work for x of any shape.
    ret_tensor = torch.zeros((length.shape[0], torch.max(length)) + tuple(x.shape[1:])) 
    cum_len = 0  
    for i, l in enumerate(length): 
        ret_tensor[i, :l] = x[cum_len: cum_len+l] 
        cum_len += l 
    return ret_tensor
```

Example:

```
in_vector = torch.rand((9,1))  
#tensor([[0.3545],
#    [0.5443],
#    [0.7550],
#    [0.9624],
#    [0.9250],
#    [0.8035],
#    [0.6877],
#    [0.4186],
#    [0.4199]])
lengths = torch.tensor([3, 4, 2])  
sequence_to_padding(in_vector, lengths)
#tensor([[[0.3545],
#     [0.5443],
#     [0.7550],
#     [0.0000]],
#
#    [[0.9624],
#     [0.9250],
#     [0.8035],
#     [0.6877]],
#
#    [[0.4186],
#     [0.4199],
#     [0.0000],
#     [0.0000]]])
```